# Google Cloud Build mysteriously wrong git hashes

Tags: github, google-cloud-build

I've been using Google Cloud Build with GitHub triggers without issue for a while now; all of a sudden today, something changed. Somehow the hashes that are showing up in Cloud Build do not correspond to any commits in any of my repositories...

[image: google cloud build wrong git hashes]

I've tried searching for documentation, or other folks who've encountered this problem, but found nothing. I uninstalled and reinstalled [the GitHub app](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/automating-builds/create-github-app-triggers#creating_github_app_triggers) to no avail.

Has anyone encountered this, and if so, how do you fix it?

**EDIT**

I found a workaround, looks like builds can be manually run

[image: manual run button]

Notice in the build history, the manual run has found a real commit, whereas the build triggered by a push to GitHub is coming up with bogus commits...

[image: manual trigger correct commit, push trigger wrong commit]

Comment: Have you maybe force-pushed a branch?

Comment: @bk2204 I did a force push _after_ the problem cropped up, but I'm not sure how that would cause the problem? Also, I tried another repo where I didn't do a force push and the problem is there as well. See my new updates, workaround discovered. Seems the issue is when a push trigger is invoked. My guess, some bad code was deployed at either Google or GitHub.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if the issue persists (especially after you trigger a manual run and find back normal existing SHA).

There was an [incident affecting Cloud Tasks scheduler jobs](https://status.cloud.google.com/incident/cloud-tasks/21001) which might have a side-effect on your build status. Considering the incident is resolved, you should not see such an issue again.

The [OP quickshiftin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/680920/quickshiftin) confirms [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66809588/google-cloud-build-mysteriously-wrong-git-hashes/66811795#comment118113802_66811795) it was more a GitHub issue than a Google Cloud one:

> - [It] looks like that incident was in `us-central1`, my servers are in `us-west1`.
> - Also, I got a response from a GitHub ticket I filed, where they said it appears to relate to changes they made "very recently" and reverted last night.
>   As of this morning, the build is working again (nothing changed on my side). >
>   Presumably the issue was from either Google or GitHub.

Comment: Thanks for this @VonC, looks like that incident was in `us-central1`, my servers are in `us-west1`. Also, I got a response from a GitHub ticket I filed, where they said it appears to relate to changes they made "very recently" and reverted last night. As of this morning, the build is working again (nothing changed on my side). Presumably the issue was from either Google or GitHub. Appreciate your answer, and the link to that status dashboard which I'll keep an eye on in the future.

Comment: @quickshiftin Thank you for the feedback. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's related to this issue, git tag generates an another ref id than the commit id when created with a comment (`git tag -a YOUR_TAG -m YOUR_COMMENT`), so the following command results may have been displayed.

`git show-ref --abbrev=7 --hash refs/tags/YOUR_TAG`
or
`git rev-parse --short refs/tags/YOUR_TAG`